# ConnectionNotEstablished when creating ActiveRecord object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have this simple class `Category`, that corresponds to the table. It inherits from another class - `Record`

**Record**

```
require_relative '../../database/contract'
require 'active_record'

class Record < ActiveRecord::Base

  def initialize
    @active = true
  end

end
```

**Category**

```
require_relative 'record'

class Category < Record
  self.table_name = Tables::CATEGORIES

  def initialize(name)
    super()
    @name = name
  end

end
```

Inside one of my test endpoints I try to create `Category` object:

```
get '/api/create' do
  category = Category.new('jewlery') #error here

  # this on the other hand, doesnt throw any error
  # conn = PGconn.open(:dbname => 'collector_test')
  # res  = conn.exec('select * from shoes')
end
```

This throws error, as stated in comments. Here are the last lines of stacktrace:

```
/Users/jacek/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb in retrieve_connection
        raise ConnectionNotEstablished, "No connection pool for #{klass}" unless pool
/Users/jacek/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb in retrieve_connection
      connection_handler.retrieve_connection(self)
```

I configured the database in `database.yml` like this (cut out production and development, since at this point I only use test)

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5

test:
  <<: *default
  database: collector_test
  username: collector
  password: password1
```

What do I miss?

Comment: You miised you development db name in the `.yml` file.. well you are doing test I see.

Comment: Didn't want to make the post too long, development setup is nearly the same, with only difference od database name: collector_dev

Comment: try this http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/ConnectionHandler.html#method-i-establish_connection methhod

Comment: should I create custom ConnectionHandler for this?